# Rails 3: trying to follow railscast #17 to add genres to my posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, checkbox

I've followed along exactly like the Railscast describes but using "genre" instead of "category," but whenever I make a post the `genre_id` shows as `NULL` and I'm getting a `WARNING: can't mass assign attribute genre_ids`

I only had `genre_id` in my post model `attr_accessible` because that's the name of the attribute, however when I change it to `genre_ids`. I get the error 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PostsController#create Could not find table 'genres_posts'`

### post form

```
<% for genre in Genre.find(:all) %>
<div>
  <%= check_box_tag "post[genre_ids][]", genre.id, @post.genre.include?(genre) %>
  <%= genre.name %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

### post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer, but here are the things you should check:

- In your code, the line `<%= check_box_tag "post[genre_ids][]", genre.id, @post.genre.include?(genre) %>` should include `genres`, not `genre`:

  `<%= check_box_tag "post[genre_ids][]", genre.id, @post.genres.include?(genre) %>`
- What Ryan Bates (I love his webcast) doesn't tell is that you need changes on your database so that your models may be stored. The reason for that is, that on a relational database, a m:n relation is normally realized by a separate table that just stores that relation only. Have a look at the ["Rails Guides: Has and belongs to many associations"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association).
- So you have to generate a standalone migration (see the [Rails Guide for that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration)) that creates that table that hold both ids to `posts` and `genres` in one table. The table should be named therefore `genres_posts`, and include the columns `genre_id` and `post_id`.

So depending on what you have done before, you may follow all the steps to reach a working example application. Good luck!

Comment: okay interesting thanks i will see if this solves the problem tomorrow